# Syntax for catching exception defined inside template class

Tags: c++

I wasn't able to find this online and it's a pretty stupid question (just about syntax):

I have the following code

tree.h-

```
#ifndef AVLTree_H_
#define AVLTree_H_

template <class ValueType,class CompareFunction>
class avlTree{
    class avlTreeException{};
public:
    class EmptyTree : public avlTreeException{};
};
#endif /* AVLTree_H_ */
```

How would I catch Empty tree? Meaning, I have another file, statistics.h-

```
#ifndef STAT_H_
#define STAT_H_
try{
    //something
}catch(avlTree::EmptyTree&){
    //something
}
#endif /* STAT_H_ */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here.

1) You have to `#include` a header file, in order to pull in the declarations in that header file.

2)

```
try{
    //something
}catch(avlTree::EmptyTree&){
    //something
}
```

Even if you `#include`d the correct header file, this still won't work. It won't work for the very simple reason that there is no such class called `avlTree::EmptyTree`, here. There isn't even a class called `avlTree`.

`avlTree` isn't a class. It's a template. Only when you instantiate a template, like:

```
avlTree<int, SomeKindOfComparisonClass>
```

do you get a class, which in this case would be called `avlTree<int, SomeKindOfComparisonClass>`; then you'll be able to catch its `EmptyTree` inner class:

```
try{
    //something
}catch(avlTree<int, SomeKindOfComparisonClass>::EmptyTree&){
    //something
}
```

Unfortunately, you can't write something like:

```
try{
    //something
}catch(template<typename ValueType,
                typename ComparisonFunction>
       avlTree<ValueType, ComparisonFunction>::EmptyTree&){
    //something
}
```

C++ doesn't work this way.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! While the last bit is a bit disappointing, in this case I had something specific.

Comment: @user336-iactuallychosethis, you can put the whole try/catch block inside a template function `template<class V, class C> void tryCatch;`. Then you can catch your empty tree as `catch(typename avlTree<V, C>::EmptyTree const &)`.